# Change in button css very slow in iOS/Android devices for Phonegap app

Tags: android, html, ios, css, jquery-mobile

I have designed a custom button using jquery mobile and css for my Phonegap mobile app.
On clicking the button just toggles on/off states and the css class is changed.
However the toggle/change is too slow on iPhone/iPad/Android devices.
There is some delay in the button rendering the toggled css.
Its actually pretty fast on desktop browsers.

All I am doing in the code is :

```
$("input[id='someid']").closest('div').removeClass("buttonUp ").addClass("buttonDown");
$("input[id='someid']").closest('div').removeClass("buttonDown").addClass("buttonUp");
```

CSS:

```
            .buttonDown {
                border:1px solid #000;font-weight:bold; cursor:pointer; text-shadow:0 1px 1px #000; text-decoration:none; background:#8FFFDD;background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#8FFFDD), color-stop(100%,#72ccb1));background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #72ccb1 0%, #8FFFDD 100%);background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8FFFDD 0%,#72ccb1 100%);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #8FFFDD 0%,#72ccb1 100%);background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #8FFFDD 0%,#72ccb1 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #8FFFDD 0%,#72ccb1 100%);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#8FFFDD', endColorstr='#72ccb1',GradientType=0 );color:#3D6AFF;
            }   


            .buttonUp {
                border:1px solid #000;font-weight:bold; cursor:pointer; text-shadow:0 1px 1px #000; text-decoration:none;background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#DD3B1B), color-stop(100%,#b12f16));background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #b12f16 0%, #DD3B1B 100%);background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #DD3B1B 0%,#b12f16 100%);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #DD3B1B 0%,#b12f16 100%);background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #DD3B1B 0%,#b12f16 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #DD3B1B 0%,#b12f16 100%);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#DD3B1B', endColorstr='#b12f16',GradientType=0 );color:#000000;
            }
```

I tried 'toggleClass()' but in vain,no effect on performance.

How can I optimize this further?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This delay is put there intentionally. It should be around 300ms.

Whatever people think, hybrid applications have a lot of disadvantages over native ones. In this case, the problem is click event detection vs swipe events. If both actions are instant application can't recognize what is a click event and what is a start swipe-start event. Because of this swipe action needs to take precedence over a click event, and the click event will only be triggered if a touch on the same spot on the screen lasts at least 300 ms.

It can be fixed if you replace click event with **[vclick](http://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/)** or touchstart event. This events don't suffer from delay problem.

If you want to read more about this take a look at my other answer regarding a difference between click/vclick/tap events. It can be found here: **[In jQuery mobile, what's the diff between tap and vclick?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15275150/1848600)**

On the other hand, if you want to leave everything as it is you can also fix this with this 3rd party jQuery Mobile plugin called **[Fastclick](https://github.com/drowne/jquery.mobile.fastclick)**. what it does is it creates fast responsive buttons without ghost clicks and the annoying **`300ms`** delay. Try it, you may like ti.

Comment: Worked like a charm!!!Lightning fast response now.Thank you very much.Also many thanks for 'Fastclick' too .