# jQuery Mobile Click Event

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, onclick, double-click

This might be the simple but I want to get in to core of this query.

I am using jQuery Mobile Latest build for one of my project. There is a problem with the response on the click event of a button.

1. I have to double click the button in order to fire it's click event and it takes time to start processing the click event handler for the button.

**Query 1:** Is it jQuery that messing it up.

**Query 2:** Can't only a single click can process jQuery's click event handler.

I have searched around the internet but did not find the appropirte resolution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do not use click event with jQuery Mobile if you don't like a delay. Basically jQuery Mobile click event has a 300ms delay and it can be event larger. You can use vclick event. It is a special jQuery Mobile click event made to bridge differences between desktop click and mobile tap. It don't suffer form delay.

Or you can use tap event or touchStart.

```
$(document).on('vclick', '#button', function(){ 
    console.log("click");
});
```

Read my other answer about click delay: [In jQuery mobile, what's the diff between tap and vclick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274809/in-jquery-mobile-whats-the-diff-between-tap-and-vclick)

Answer (score 1):

When you are on your mobile device viewing a website using jQuery Mobile, the click event has a 300ms delay.

Make sure you use jQuery Mobile's [Tap](http://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/)

Also, I find it helpful when I am building a webapp with jQuery Mobile to use `e.preventDefault()` because if you don't, a tap event might also trigger on the element underneath it if the element you tap disappears with on your tap event. ie. `.hide()`

Example:

```
$('.button').on('tap', function(e){
      console.log('tapped');

      $(this).hide();
      e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me it force the click event for jquerymobile

```
$("#button").trigger('click');
```

source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/experiments/api-viewer/docs/bind/index.html