# jquery mobile 1.4 + phonegap 3, which button event : click tap vmousedown

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

Hi what are the best practices and fastest events for click events with buttons, links and selects for Phonegap 3.3 and jquery mobile 1.4 ?

Click, tap, vmousedown ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with jQuery Mobile then it is a vclick.

Unlike tap and click it will work on desktop and mobile browsers alike, and unlike click event this one don't suffer from 300ms delay.

Read my other **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274809/in-jquery-mobile-whats-the-diff-between-tap-and-vclick/15275150#15275150)** to find out more.

```
$(document).on('vclick', '#someButton', function(){ 

});
```